# What is a convolutional ply?

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to recreate the result of this [paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/convolutional-neural-networks-for-speech-recognition-2/). They use the term convolutional ply for the neural network they apply on the audio spectogram.  I am not sure I understand what a convolutional ply is, and how it differs from an ordinary convolutional neural network (cnn).

The paper states this as being the difference:

> A convolution ply differs from a standard, fully connected hidden
>   layer in two important aspects, however. First, each convolutional
>   unit receives input only from a local area of the input. This means
>   that each unit represents some features of a local region of the 
>   input. Second, the units of the convolution ply can themselves be
>   organized into a number of feature maps, where all units in the same
>   feature map share the same weights but receive input from different
>   locations of the lower layer

Which to me sound like a ordinary cnn network. What is the difference?